# MonoGame(XNA) Won't detect multiple controllers(Using PlayerIndex)

Tags: c#, controller, xna, monogame, xbox

I've been trying to get two controllers working in a MonoGame Project I'm working on and the only Controller that seems to work is 'PlayerIndex.One'. I've tried switching the controller indexes and it won't work whenever it is on anything except 'PlayerIndex.One'

Here is my code, it runs without errors but it still won't work.

```
if (Robot.IsConnected)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Buttons.A) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Buttons.B) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Buttons.Y) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Buttons.X))
            {
                if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Y == ButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    Robot.SendMessage(driveRobot, straight);

                }
if (Robot2.IsConnected)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.Two).IsButtonDown(Buttons.A) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.Two).IsButtonDown(Buttons.B) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.Two).IsButtonDown(Buttons.Y) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.Two).IsButtonDown(Buttons.X))
            {
                if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.Two).Buttons.Y == ButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    Robot.SendMessage(driveRobot2, straight);

                }
```

Comment: Are you sure that Windows actually does recognize the two controllers at the same time? Cause if Windows doesn't even detect the second controller, it's not a MonoGame problem. Check Device Manager, or try downloading some third-party software to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

You actually deliver the message to `Robot` the second time as well. Shouldn't this be `Robot2`

Current:

```
Robot.SendMessage(driveRobot2, straight);
```

Should be:

```
Robot2.SendMessage(driveRobot2, straight);
```